# Why IndexOf returns always Zero?

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, indexof

Could someone point me why the IndexOf returns always zero in the following text?

```
Dim Str as string = "<p><img class=floatLeft width="330"src="http://www.com"></p><p>"
Dim Idx as integer = Str.IndexOf("<p>")
```

Is there any other way, of getting the index?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the *first* occurrence of `<p>` is at the beginning of the string, and strings (along with many other things) are zero-indexed.

If you want to get the index of the *last*-occurring `<p>`, you can use `Str.LastIndexOf("<p>")`.

If you want to get the index of the *next*-occurring `<p>` after the first, and assuming the string *always starts* with at least one `<p>`, you can use `Str.IndexOf("<p>", "<p>".Length())` so it starts searching from after the first occurrence.

---

By the way, you have a syntax error in your `Dim Str` line, you need to escape double quotes with extra double quotes:

```
Dim Str as string = "<p><img class=""floatLeft"" width=""330"" src=""http://www.com""></p><p>"
```