# vb.net get certain characters from a string

Tags: vb.net

i have strings that i am using in vb.net, i want to be able to get certain parts of the string.

one example would be:

1 x Example Item 1

from this i would want to get the `1` and `Example Item 1`

then there could be an item which is:

10 x Example 2

so i would want to get the `10` and `Example 2`

i thought about using something like `substring`:

```
Dim substring As String = Substring(0, 3)
```

but this isnt always going to work depending on the quantity of the item (if its 1/2 or 3 digits long)

there is also some strings that will simlply just be `Example Item 10` with no `1 x` or `10 x`at the beginning, how can i see if it starts with a `1/10 x` or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why IndexOf returns always Zero?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691987/why-indexof-returns-always-zero)

Comment: `input.Split({" x "}, 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
Dim subject = "1 x Example 2"
Dim leftPart, rightPart As String
If Regex.IsMatch(subject, "\d+\sx\s") Then
    Dim splitText As String() = subject.Split({" x "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    leftPart = splitText(0)
    rightPart = splitText(1)
Else
    'Treat it as you wish.
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    Dim substring As String = "10 x Example 2"
    Dim myStrings() As String

    myStrings = MyStringParser(substring)
    substring = "Example 4"
    myStrings = MyStringParser(substring)
    substring = " x Example 4"
    myStrings = MyStringParser(substring)

Public Function MyStringParser(value As String) As String()

    Dim returnValue() As String = {"", ""}

    If value.Length > 0 Then
        If value.Contains(" x ") Then
            returnValue = value.Replace(" x ", "|").Split("|"c)
        Else
            returnValue(1) = value
        End If
    Else
        returnValue(1) = value
    End If

    Return returnValue

End Function
```

Comment: Then give us all the possible combinations and you can solve it with Regex.    This will work with a string that starts with 1/10 x Example 10000.

Comment: i cant give all the strings as they are always going to be different. there are many which will just be standard strings with no numbers and then others which will always start with [NUM] x then the NAME of the item

Comment: so, there will be 2 options (NUM x Item Name / Item Name)

Comment: You can use `String.Contains(" x ")`

Comment: whats the best way to identify what type of string it is ?

Comment: @charlie See my new answer.

Comment: There are several ways to accomplish this take your pick.